# Is $N$ a subgroup of $H$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $N$ be a finite, normal subgroup of $G$, and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:H]$ is finite. We were tasked to show that if $[G:H]$ and $|N|$ are relatively prime, then $N\leq H$.

Initially, I thought of just using the Lagrange Theorem for each group-subgroup relationships that I have above, but realized that $|G|$ and $|H|$ might be groups of infinite order. I am having trouble and I don't know if what I thought initially is correct. Just give me hints on how to start and I'll do the rest. I still want to prove it on my own. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: Since $N$ is normal, $NH$ is a subgroup. Consider its index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $N$ is normal, $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$, and since $HN/N \cong H/(H \cap N)$, we have $|HN:H|=|N:H \cap N|$. These last indices are finite and divide $|G:H|$ and $|N|$. Since these last numbers are relatively prime, it follows that $|HN:H|=1=|N: H \cap N|$. Hence, $HN=H$, which is equivalent to $N \subseteq H$.

Comment: Sorry, how to get  $|HN:H|=|N:H\cap{N}|$ by the above isomorphism? I mean I only can get $|HN:N|=|H/H\cap{N}|$ by it.

Comment: This is due to the second isomorphic theorem and cardinal numbers. Alternatively define a map $f$ from the cosets of $N$ in $HN$, $\{hN : h \in H\}$ to those of $H \cap N$ in $N$, by $f(hN):=h(H \cap N)$. Show that $f$ is well-defined and bijective.

Comment: But how to show $f$ is surjective?For any $n(H\cap{N})$, it can't say $n\in{H}$  unless we have proven that $N\subset{H}$, which makes me puzzled.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, the text should be: define a map $f$ from the right cosets of $H$ in $HN$, $\{Hn: n \in N\}$ to those of $H \cap N$ in $N$, by $f(Hn)=(H \cap N)n$. This map $f$ is well-defined and bijective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and patience, I get what you mean.